# Traversing a binary tree using a Node interface and an abstract Traverser class using a strategy pattern for order

Tags: java

I have written this code for depth first tree traversals.
It feels like a lot of boilerplate, and I want to refactor it to remove this boilerplate.
However I haven't done a lot of refactoring before, and I don't really know where to start.

The code mostly consists of:

- Three interfaces

  - `Node`, which defines two methods returning the left or right child of a node.
  - `TreeTraverser`, which is simply an `Iterator` for `Node` implementing classes.
  - `TraversalStateIncrementer`, which defines two methods, `inital()` which returns an enum signifying the first `Node` to handle in an order (such as `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `SELF`, mirroring the order of function calls in a recursive implementation)
- One `enum`

  - `TraversalState`: `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `SELF`, or `POP`. See `TraversalStateIncrementer`. The `POP` is used to signify that a `Node` should be popped off the stack (an internal node stack in the `abstract class`)
- One `abstract class` with a `private static inner class`

  - `AbstractOrderTreeTraverser` which implements all boilerplate except the order of traversal, which is provided by an injected `TraversalStateIncrementer`.

`Node.java`

```
package dev.nylander.util.tree;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface Node<NODE extends Node<NODE>> {
    Optional<NODE> getLeft();
    Optional<NODE> getRight();
}
```

`TreeTraverser.java`

```
package dev.nylander.util.tree;

import java.util.Iterator;

public interface TreeTraverser<NODE extends Node<NODE>> extends Iterator<NODE> {
}
```

`TraversalStateIncrementer.java`

```
package dev.nylander.util.tree;

interface TraversalStateIncrementer {
    TraversalState initial();
    TraversalState increment(TraversalState state);
}
```

`TraversalState.java`

```
package dev.nylander.util.tree;

enum TraversalState {
    RIGHT, LEFT, SELF, POP
}
```

`AbstractOrderTreeTraverser.java`
Here's where the "magic" happens.

```
package dev.nylander.util.tree;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Stack;

abstract class AbstractOrderTreeTraverser<NODE extends Node<NODE>> implements TreeTraverser<NODE> {
    private final TraversalStateIncrementer incrementer;
    private final NODE root;
    private final Stack<NodeStatePair<NODE>> traversalStack = new Stack<>();
    private NODE next = null;

    public AbstractOrderTreeTraverser(NODE root, TraversalStateIncrementer incrementer) {
        this.root = root;
        this.incrementer = incrementer;
        setupStack();
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean hasNext() {
        traverseUntilNext();
        return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public final NODE next() {
        traverseUntilNext();
        if (next == null)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return popNext();
    }

    private void setupStack() {
        traversalStack.push(newNodeStatePair(root));
    }

    private NodeStatePair<NODE> newNodeStatePair(NODE node) {
        return new NodeStatePair<>(node, incrementer.initial());
    }

    private void traverseUntilNext() {
        while (next == null && !traversalStack.isEmpty()) {
            NodeStatePair<NODE> current = traversalStack.peek();
            TraversalState currentState = current.state();
            current.setState(incrementer.increment(currentState));
            handleState(currentState);
        }
    }

    private void handleState(TraversalState state) {
        NodeStatePair<NODE> current = traversalStack.peek();
        switch (state) {
            case LEFT:
                Optional<NODE> optionalLeft = current.node().getLeft();
                pushAsNodeStatePair(optionalLeft);
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                Optional<NODE> optionalRight = current.node().getRight();
                pushAsNodeStatePair(optionalRight);
                break;
            case SELF:
                next = current.node();
                break;
            case POP:
                traversalStack.pop();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void pushAsNodeStatePair(Optional<NODE> possibleNode) {
        possibleNode.ifPresent(node -> traversalStack.push(newNodeStatePair(node)));
    }

    private NODE popNext() {
        NODE poppedNext = next;
        next = null;
        return poppedNext;
    }

    private static class NodeStatePair<NODE extends Node<NODE>> {
        private final NODE node;
        private TraversalState state;

        NodeStatePair(NODE node, TraversalState initialState) {
            this.node = node;
            this.state = initialState;
        }

        public void setState(TraversalState state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public TraversalState state() {
            return state;
        }

        public NODE node() {
            return node;
        }

    }
}
```

How should I go about refactoring this code?

Comment: Have you considered implementing the tree traversal as a stream? It would simplify traversal state management and allow for trivial parallelization.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen while I am familiar with the convenience of streams, I am not familiar with their implementation. I will look into the docs and see what I can do. Thanks!

Comment: See [Spliterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html)